# draw graph multiplatform (IOS, WindowsPhone, Android) library

Tags: android, iphone, silverlight, windows-phone-7, graph

I'm working on a multiplatform application for windowsphone, iphone and android. I do this using visualstudio(phone sdk) with monoplugin (monotouch and mono for android for the other two platforms). The c# you write the code in is compiled to native code for al three platform.

my Question(S):

1. I'm looking for a graph drawing library that is based on the .net (silverlight) framework. Because if I get the library working on windowsphone, it should be able to work on the other two platforms (with the help of mono). So, does anyone know (or recommend) a graph library?
2. Has anyone here ever done something similar and if so? what library did you use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably won't find such library - unless you resort to using a HTML View with a Javascript  Drawing Library on all platforms. I for one would stick to exposing the relevant data from your View Model and use some code-behind in your platform specific view to adapt your graph library of choice for each of the platforms to deal with the data exposed by your View Model.

Comment: Okay. Are there no functions in .net silverlight to draw a graph.. Because if there are, i will consider making my own library. using the standard .net/silverlight libraries. Atleast, thanks for answering so quick! :)

Answer (score 1):

There is one library i found, that atleast implements the basic draw functions across the three mono sdk's.

It can be found here:

https://github.com/praeclarum/CrossGraphics